# Hyphens in windows phone IE

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-7

Need to have hyphens in IE on windows phone 8(or better on both 7/8). I'm using web browser control to show content and i'm embedding some css to make typography prettier. It seems that mobile version of IE is really cropped! For example `p:first-child:first-letter` is not working..`hyphens:auto` is not working too. Are there workarounds to add hyphens to margined text?

**PS** trying [Hyphenator.js](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/downloads/list) now, but there is a problem with it, since can't find the way to include local script into the page in webbrowser control(im using NavigateToString).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference local javascript files, but you need to load them into Isolated Storage first.

This is how you can load them into local storage.

```
var fileResourceStreamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("scripts/Hyphenator.js", UriKind.Relative));
if (fileResourceStreamInfo != null)
{
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fileResourceStreamInfo.Stream))
{
    byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)fileResourceStreamInfo.Stream.Length);

    string strBaseDir = "scripts";

    if(!appStorage.DirectoryExists(strBaseDir))
    {
        //Debug.WriteLine("Creating Directory :: " + strBaseDir);
        appStorage.CreateDirectory(strBaseDir);
    }

    // This will truncate/overwrite an existing file, or 
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream outFile = appStorage.OpenFile(AppRoot + "scripts/Hyphenator.js", FileMode.Create))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Writing data for " + AppRoot + "scripts/Hyphenator.js" + " and length = " + data.Length);
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(outFile))
        {
            writer.Write(data);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Then you can reference them like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/Hyphenator.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you, will try it asap.

Comment: are you sure i can access my script file as scripts/myJavascript.js? Used this method http://jesseliberty.com/2011/10/27/background-audio-part-ii-copying-audio-files-to-isolated-storage/ and im accessing script with this code(file is in root directory): `<script src='Hyphenator.js'....` not working..But if instead of local src i give it full address to Hyphenator.js on the web-it works!

Comment: When you can reference Hyphenator.js from the web, go ahead with that approach. My understanding was you want to package the js-file with the app and load it from inside the app and not being dependent on an internet connection.

Comment: yes, you understood me correctly: i want to open page with hypens to work even without internet. For now i open the file Hypernator.js from isolated storage, save it as a string and append that string to my page.

Comment: I edited the provided implementation to mirror your specific file